# How to hide a parameter that can't be changed (Crystal)?

Tags: parameters, hidden, crystal-reports-2008

I have a report in InfoView that has in a footer showing the effective date of the data.
This comes from a stored procedure whose parameter is the name of the table that the report comes from.  Since the user can't redesign the report, there is no reason for him or her to be offered a chance to change that name.  I have hunted for something to suppress that from the parameter prompts, but haven't found it.

The Edit for the parameter has an option to set the default value which works.
It also has several boolean options which I cannot change (Why?!)  And at the top of the list is an option titled "Show on (Viewer) Panel" [sic] which is set to "Do not show"  Nevertheless, viewing the report first asks for parameters, and this one is right there on the form with the rest.

I can translate "Hide '@Table_Name'" into C# or VB but this report isn't served from either.

One web page in my web search says you have to turn it off in the select expert, but that only shows formulae, not parameters (nor tables nor sprocs).

Tons of web pages tell how to hide the entire parameter setting, but the others have to be offered to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this isn't an issue for most people.  But I finally figured out a "not-too-bad" workaround.  Instead of making the value a parameter that never changes, make it a hard-coded value in a Crystal-side SQL command.

In other words, DB expert, Add command, type the whole SQL instead of calling a stored procedure or view.